# HID input on linux for games

Tags: linux, input, hid

What is the best way to capture HID input on linux for games? I don't need anything special. Just mouse and keyboard. Right now I'm using Xlib. I have a separate input thread, which has its own connection to the X Server (Display instance) and it handles events for main render window. It is working just fine, but it is a bit limited. For example, I'm missing mouse raw input.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening and reading device files in /dev/input?